# Tags: tax, taxes, taxation

Tags: discussion

Should we unify these?

https://economics.stackexchange.com/tags/taxation/synonyms

https://economics.stackexchange.com/tags/taxes/synonyms

https://economics.stackexchange.com/tags/tax/synonyms

Answer (score 3):

Late response from me, but I would be in favor of merging the tags. I am happy to just have one tag and have the others be tag synonyms. Don't think there's much point in separating them, unless others feel differently.

Comment: There have been no counterarguments for a months, so I'd say go ahead without further conultation and use your powers to merge them. As an optional second and third step, declare yourself first consul and later Emperor.

Comment: Taxation was the most common tag, so I have merged the other tags into that. I will however decline to call myself emperor. Our mod triumvirate works just fine :^)

Comment: NB also kept the other two consuls (: